# Cron jobs not running but http://file.php runs fine from browser?

Tags: php, command-line, cron

I've read here on Stackoverflow that paths inside the file could be a problem, but it seems to fail at the first thing it read... Other than this I have no clue, even after checking many questions/answers here. At some point I thought it was because I used a shorthand version of PHP tag ("`<? ?>`" instead of "`<?php ?>`").

So basically, when I type the url in a browser "http://site.com/file.php" it runs fine (it's a mysql backup + send by email). But when I try to run the same file with cron, I get errors...

My server is on MediaTemple, the cron is:

`php -c /home/xxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/html/777/fnc/filenamexxxxxx.php --'bckup=1'`

Here is the error:

> PHP: syntax error, unexpected '(' in /nfs/c08/h02/mnt/xxxxxxx/domains/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/html/777/fnc/filenamexxxxxx.php on line 2

Here's the first part of the code (as it is, no edit, except website address + emails):

```
<?php
// envoi un courriel de tous les rv des 7 prochains jours pour chaque clinique à toutes les 30min (cron script lancé par cpanel)

session_start();
$bypass = 1;
//$_SESSION['rep'] = "777/";

include_once("inc_includes_principaux.php");
//error_reporting(E_ERROR);

// to send an automated backup by email, just link to this file like this with CRON:
if ($_GET['bckup']){

// va chercher les infos de connection
include_once('inc_bd_connexion.php');


// get cliniques
    $cliniques = _get_clinique_info();//_p($cliniques);_x();
    $date = date('Ymd');
    $date7jours = _get_x_days_before($date, 7, '+');//_e($date7jours);_x();


// iterate cliniques and send email
foreach ($cliniques as $cliniqueid => $v) {

    $emailthis = _get_rv_printformat($date, $date7jours, $cliniqueid);// start, end, id

    // send email to users
    _email('emailaddressxxxxxxxx', $emailthis, 'LCJG - Horaire de '.$v['A29'].' du '._date_en_texte($date).' au '._date_en_texte($date7jours),'emailaddressxxxxxxxx');
    sleep(1);//give a break to the server and let some other tasks execute
    _email('emailaddressxxxxxxxx', $emailthis, 'LCJG - Horaire de '.$v['A29'].' du '._date_en_texte($date).' au '._date_en_texte($date7jours),'emailaddressxxxxxxxx');
    unset($emailthis);

    echo 'LCJG - Horaire de <b>'.$v['A29'].'</b> pour les 7 prochains jours envoyé par courriel.<br>';
}
}

?>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid changing my code and since I wanted an easy to implement solution, I followed Dagon suggestion to use wget, but instead used CURL. So I could keep my code exactly as it was and just call my file in order to execute it at a specific time.

The code that worked without making changes to my script is:

```
curl www.aaaaaaa.com/file-to-execute.php?arg=1
```

And with this, the cron ran perfectly and now everything is fine. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you cant start a session in the cli environment

so to run it in both add

```
if (!isset($argc)) {
    //Not  CLI
    session_start();
}
```

OR

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli')
{
   // is cli
}
```

your $_GET wont work either, the value will be in the $argv array. You need to some work on how a script runs in CLI vs via a web server.

Comment: this is wrong approach. You should use `php_sapi_name()` to find out how are you invoked: http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

Comment: 'wrong', or just one of many ways? what can't you do 10 way in php?

Comment: well I consider it "wrong", because `isset($argc)` tells if variable is set, but you want to know if you are running from shell or not and not check if variable is set or not.

Comment: $argc is always set in the cli, but anyway alternative added.

Comment: Yep, that's better. +1 now ;)

Comment: Why do I heave to re-write tons of code to make this work? On my old Netfirm server this used to work perfectly: I only had to give a common link www.aaaa.com/file-to-execute.php?arg=1 and it would run it like if I would write this in the url. Can I just do the same with my new server?

Comment: at a guess it was not calling the cron jobs via cli (as every one else does and should), bit through a werbserver via wget et al

Comment: So there is no simple way to do it via "normal url" way (even if it's not "perfect") and to make it work without rewriting code?

Comment: from the cli run `wget http://site.com/script.php` if that works, you can set that as the cron job. if it works i would recommend `wget -q -t 5 --delete-after http://site.com/script.php` gets rid of output which i assume you wouldn't want

Comment: Thanks! I actually found and used curl to do it. It saved me tremendous time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `-c` do you mean to use the `-f` CLI parameter?

```
$ php --help
-c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
-f <file>        Parse and execute <file>.
```

It looks like php might be trying to parse your script as an INI file and then looking for your script from STDIN. (Otherwise, I'm not sure why php would be ignoring the `-c` and proceeding to execute your PHP file as the target script.)