# Cron job doesnt perform the same as typing url into browser

Tags: php, curl, cron

I am having trouble with a cron job I created.  I have a php script located on my server that will get the recent arrest data from a website and store it in database.  The problem is when the cron job runs it will get all the images but doesnt get the details.  **However if I type the url to the script in the browser and run it then it works perfectly.**  Im not sure but is there something I should be doing that I am not, or is there anyway to simulate an actual browser loading the page in cron (maybe that is the problem?)

Here is what I am doing:

Cron job (URL CHANGED): `0  23  *   *   *   curl https://mydomain.com/some-path/store.php`

PHP script here: pastebin.com/1Z3Bn73U

I looked at [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056353/cron-jobs-not-running-but-http-file-php-runs-fine-from-browser) on stackoverflow but nothing has seemed to work, I tried `wget, wget --spider, curl, curl mycommand >/dev/null 2>&1`

Please help, I have been at this for days and I really dont want to have to manually load each script everyday if possible.

Comment: are you useing $_SERVER to fetch data from the website?? if yes then it might be causing problem. it is accessible on browser but might not be in the cmd line.

Comment: are you doing get request to your web service?

Comment: `91. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);`

Comment: Yes, from the pastebin if you look at line 91 I am using    ‘curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);’, so what is my solution to that if that is the culprit?

Comment: I think part of the webpage you want to download might be generated with javascript code and is not visible as part of the html that is downloaded. It might also be rendered asynchronously after ajax calls to the server. I such cases you would have to use a headless browser emulation do perform those actions from command line. There is a tool to make this possible and it is based on Webkit engine like Google Chrome. This tool is `phantomjs` but to make it work one has to know its way around programming.

Comment: @mnmnc you are exactly right about the calls the website makes- I am familiar with some codes and can look to figure out what does what, I have never used a headless browser though, could you tell me where a good start would be looking at the examples of phantom.js and provide it as an answer so I can accept?  Thanks for all of your helps guys

Comment: @Derek When I started with phantomjs i've went trough the QuickStart on phnatomjs website: http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html. This is a good starting point. After that only JavaScript and NodeJS tutorials will be able to give more detailed information.